# C++ References and Java References

Tags: java, c++

//C++ Example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int doHello (std::string&);
int main() {
    std::string str1 = "perry";
    cout << "String=" << str1 << endl;
    doHello(str1);
    cout << "String=" << str1 << endl; // prints pieterson
    return 0;
}

int doHello(std::string& str){
    str = "pieterson";
    cout << "String=" << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above case, as expected the string 'str1' reference is modified when str reference is modified

//Java Example

```
public class hello {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str1 = "perry";
        System.out.println("String=" + str1);
        doHello(str1);
        System.out.println("String=" + str1); // does not prints pieterson
    }

    public static void doHello(String str){
        str = "pieterson";
        System.out.println("String = " + str);
    }
}
```

In Java, String str and String str1 are two different objects initially referencing the same String, so when we change str reference in doHello(), str1 reference does not get changed.

How can we achieve C++ style functionality in Java with Strings, Collections such as List, Vectors, other Objects.

**Update:**

Thanks Jon for a wonderful explaination, I believe any Java beginner will surely come across this question. 
Let me explain what problem i ran into while using lists.

```
//bad doHello() 

void doHello(List inputList) { 
    inputList = getListFromAnyFunction(); // wrong, didnt work 
} 

// good doHello 

void doHello(List inputList) { 
    inputList.addAll(getListFromAnyFunction()); // worked 
}
```

Thanks Powell and Harshath for your explainations and code samples.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java does not have pass by reference (which you were using in the C++ code) at all. The references are passed by value. (The values of `str` and `str1` aren't objects at all, they're references - it really helps to keep the two concepts very separate.)

Typically you would use a return value to return a new reference if you need to:

```
str1 = doHello(str1);
```

Note that String is slightly different to List etc, because strings are immutable. To modify a collection (well, any mutable collection) you don't need to create a new one, you just modify the *object* via the original reference:

```
public static void addHello(List<String> items)
{
    items.add("Hello");
}
```

You could then call this like so:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
addHello(list);
System.out.println(list.get(0)); // "Hello"
```

The difference between mutating an existing *object* and changing the value of a variable to refer to a *different* object is crucial. If you want to leave the existing collection alone and create a new one, you'd have to do that explicitly:

```
public static List<String> withHello(List<String> items)
{
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(items);
    newList.add("Hello");
    return newList;
}
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
List<String> empty = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newList = withHello(empty);
System.out.println(empty.size()); // Prints 0
System.out.println(newList.size()); // Prints 1
```

Does this answer everything you needed?

Comment: This is slightly wrong,  to be really strictly right, Java passes all objects (anything which is not a basic type, e.g. int but not Integer) by reference transparently and ,as you know, you don't have any pointers. This is way you can crash Java programs with null 'pointer' exceptions, even though the language doesn't have them.
One of the most confusing projects I ever did was a combined Java and C++ one, the two look similar, but require thinking about problems in a subtly different way.

Comment: I disagree with Chris here. The value of a reference-type expression is a reference, and that reference is passed *by value* to methods. That may be implemented as a pointer (in which case it's passing pointer-by-value, which is still different to passing object-by-reference) of course. The class "NullPointerException" was basically unfortunately named. Claiming that Java passes objects by reference has caused a great deal of confusion in the past. People who know what "by reference" really mean then expect to be able to write "swap" methods etc.

Comment: See http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm and numerous Stack Overflow questions and answers for more :)

Comment: (In particular, I'd say it's hard to claim that Java uses pass-by-reference in the face of section 8.4.1, as quoted in the article linked above: When the method or constructor is invoked (§15.12), the values of the actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter variables [...] " See the bit that says "the values of the actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter variables"? That's basically the definition of pass-by-value: evaluate the expression, pass the value.

Comment: Actually -- make that "thanks for the link" to avoid confusion ;)

Answer (score 15):

### Parameter passing, call-by-reference and call-by-value (short answer)

In C++ there are two parameter passing forms, ***call by value*** and ***call by reference***. (The better name for *call-by-value* is *call-by-new-L-value*, but I digress.)

In Java programs all parameters are passed *by value*. [There are some people that think that Java passes objects by reference, but they're wrong—see the long answer below—Java passes *the reference value* of Objects, but that is not the same thing at all.]

The *value* of a Java Object (and what is passed) is a *pointer* to the object (confusingly, but accurately, called a reference to the object), and calling a Java object method, for example, `obj.meth()`, de-references the *pointer* value of `obj` before calling the method on the object found there.

In C++ the same call would look like: `obj->meth()`.

If you manipulate the object (for example, by calling a method on it) passed as a parameter to a method in Java, this may modify the object, and if the caller still has a variable holding that object it can see these changes.  If you merely assign to the (local) parameter variable, you simply update the pointer stored in the local variable—the object is unaffected, and the caller will not notice this.

So, the short answer to your question is that Java passes by value, and the call-by-reference mechanism of C++ is not available in Java.

### Parameters, variables and call-by-value (long answer)

To understand what's going on here we need to understand the mechanics of variables and parameter passing a bit more.

#### Variables

Generally speaking, a variable in a programming language is an identifier that is associated with a value. Variables that denote values manipulated at *runtime* (we are here ignoring macro variables, constants that are 'compiled away', and so forth) have to have ***two*** values associated with them.  Here is an example that explains why:

```
int a = 0;
a = a + 1;
```

`a` is the variable, and in the line `a = a + 1;` it is referred to *twice*. Once, (on the *right hand side* of the `=`) the value `0` is meant and once, (on the *left hand side* of the `=`) the *location* of the value of `a` is meant (that is, *where the integer value of* `a` *is stored*). Only by accessing the location can the program **update** the value which is contained in it.

These two values associated with a variable are called the **R-value** and the **L-value**. (These names were invented by Christopher Strachey; I'm a fan.) Other constructs in the language refer to one or other of these values depending upon context. For example:

```
a[x-1] = x;
```

refers to the R-value of `x` twice (even though one is on the left-hand-side of the `=`), but only the L-value of `a` (or at least one of the elements of the array `a`).

In most programming languages, we explicitly manipulate the R-values of variables, and leave the compiler (from the form of the program) to manage the L-values automatically for us. We have to understand them a bit (in C, in particular with arrays, we assume a lot about L-values), but most of the time we don't have to know the mechanics.

#### Call by value

Look at this call:

```
int p=1;
obj.meth(p);
…
void meth(int a) {…a…}
```

What happens to the parameters here? First the R-value of `p` is calculated, then, when `meth` is 'entered', a new variable `a` is constructed. It is given a new L-value (this location is normally on a stack of some sort) and the R-value of the parameter is stored in the location.

Now, when `a` appears in `meth` it has the same R-value that `p` had (initially) and a new L-value. Changes to `a`'s R-value make no difference to the variable `p`. This is called *call-by-value* (more properly, *call-by-new-L-value*).

#### Call by reference

Look at this C++ call:

```
int p=1;
obj.meth(p);
…
void meth(int& a) {…a…}
```

Here the L-value of the parameter `p` is calculated, and when the variable `a` is constructed it is “given” the *same* L-value as `p`. Then any use of `a` in the body of `meth` is just like a use of `p`. Assignment, for example will alter the stored value in `p` as well as (apparently) the value in `a`.

Java doesn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have written in java is equivalent to this C++ code:

```
int main() {
    std::string *s1;
    s1 = new std::string("perry");
    std::cout << s1->c_str() << std::endl;
    doMojo( s1 );
    std::cout << s1->c_str() << std::endl; // not pieterson
}
void doMojo( std::string *str ) {
    str = new std::string("pieterson");
    std::cout << str->c_str() << std::end;
}
```

perhaps now you see what happens. The C++ references actually wrap around the pointers.. so without the references your code would look like this:

```
int main() {
    std::string *s1;
    s1 = new std::string("perry");
    std::cout << s1->c_str() << std::endl;
    doMojo( s1 );
    std::cout << s1->c_str() << std::endl; // now pieterson!
}
void doMojo( std::string *&str ) {
    str = new std::string("pieterson");
    std::cout << str->c_str() << std::end;
}
```

notice the innocuous ampersand:

```
void doMojo( std::string *&str ) {
```

That really is the secret. This, and the previous answer that explains about immutability of java strings should make you appretiate the difference between java and c++ references.

Cheers,

jrh.

Answer (score 0):

String in java is immutable, it can not be modified once created. Using assignment in doHello() actually create a new string object instead of modifying the existing one. In result, the 2 java references(one in main, the other in doHello) to string reference to 2 different strings respectively. That's why you see different results between C++ and Java.