# C++ lambda const value reference got deleted in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, reference, lambda

I have encountered the following situation:

```
void Plugin::sendMessage(const QString& jid, const QString &message) {
    qDebug() << "SENDING TO JID1: " << jid;
    QtConcurrent::run([&, this]() {
        qDebug() << "SENDING TO JID2: " << jid;
    }
}
```

produces next output:

> SENDING TO JID1:  "test@xmpp.org"
>
> SENDING TO JID2:  "

and then it crashes. It looks like `jid` is no longer exists in the lambda, but why? How then can I use the variables by references in this code?

Comment: The problem is most likely that you have no control over when the lambda function in the `QConcurrent` is executed, and that might mean that the string that is referenced by `jid` have been destructed. Capture by value instead.

Comment: Yes, it works if I capture by value, just wondered why compiler can't prolong existence of the reference until lambda execution.

Comment: Because the compiler have no idea what's happening, or when (if ever) the reference will be needed.

Comment: Okay, you may answer the question and I'll accept it. If you don't want too I may delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are coming from Java background, note that references in C++ and Java mean something very different. In Java references are garbage collected and therefore it is easy to prolong their lifetime as needed. In C++ there is no garbage collection and a reference variable lifetime has little relation to the lifetime of the referenced object.

See also [C++ References and Java References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979814/c-references-and-java-references) or [Programmers Why do C++ and Java both use the notion of “reference” but not in the same sense?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223471/why-do-c-and-java-both-use-the-notion-of-reference-but-not-in-the-same-sense)  for some more explanation.